# how to save chronometer time into a variable ?

Tags: android

If I hit the stop button and the chronometer stops at 00:07 how can I save that value as an int ?

```
View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Timer.stop();
        saveTime = Timer.getBase();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        TableScreen.class).putExtra("timer",saveTime);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by `save`? Do you want it in `SharedPreferences`, do you want it in a `File`, do you want it set via `HttpPost` to a web server, do you want to send the value to a different `Activity`?

Comment: Could you please explain more about your question. I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: You save it as a long, in milliseconds. Then convert back to proper value for displaying purposes.

Comment: `long saveTime = Timer.getBase();` does this code saves the chronometer time once I stop the time ? how would I then convert that time to an int and display that value in a different activity ?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out guys.

```
 View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Timer.stop();
        saveTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - Timer.getBase();
        int seconds = (int)(saveTime/1000 % 60);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        TableScreen.class).putExtra("timer",seconds);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```